# ¿como presentar imagenes del mismo tamaño?

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc

tengo varias imagenes de diferente tamaño.
Como hago para mostralas del mismo tamaño, como si estuviera mostrando productos?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar los atributos `width` (ancho) y `height` (alto), pero lo más óptimo es que el servidor sirva las imágenes con el tamaño y resolución adecuados a donde se va a mostrar.

Así evitas descargar imágenes más grandes de lo necesario, con lo que mejorará el rendimiento de tu página, y que las imágenes aparezcan distorsionadas por cargar su relación de aspecto:

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/48/bd/3f/48bd3f6e928d7cb4b8d499cb0f96b8a8--despicable-minions-funny-minion.jpg" />
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/despicableme/images/2/2b/Stuart.png/revision/latest?cb=20161108162855" />
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Minions_characters.png" />
<img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/despicableme/images/1/1d/Kevin_minions.png/revision/latest?cb=20160929061515" />
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f6/18/47/f61847d8ef0fce193378bffa425acbe4--minions-love-minions-.jpg" />
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ee/fd/4d/eefd4d45c0cd9dd7f3d86b4b49e7fc72--cute-minions-minion-stuff.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.kissfm.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/minions-01.jpg" />
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91u1OKpJzWL._SY450_.jpg" />
```